# I want connect Google Cloud Vision to my flutter app

Tags: flutter, rest, google-cloud-vision, dio, vision-api

i want connect google cloud Vision to my flutter app

this is my code

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

const _apiPREFIX = "https://vision.googleapis.com";


class Server {
  Future<void> postReq() async {
    Response response;
    Dio dio = Dio();
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "requests": [
        {
          "image": {
            "source": {
              "imageUri":
                  "https://image.msscdn.net/images/goods_img/20200729/1530505/1530505_2_500.jpg?t=20210902101946"
            }
          },
          "features": [
            {"type": "LABEL_DETECTION", "maxResults": 1}
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    try {
      response = await dio.post(
        "$_apiPREFIX/v1/images:asyncBatchAnnotate?key=(my api key)",data: data
      );
      print(response.data.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  }
}

Server server = Server();
```

i have google Api key but how can use this key

i recieve 403 error
how can i fix this problem,,,

please help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use this package to retrieve the authentication tokens and pass it in the request.

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/gcloud/install

More details: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#curl